# Files stored in AWS bucket to only be downloaded if users are logged into Laravel app. Not by directly going to URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I only want users to be able to download files which are saved in my AWS bucket if they are logged into my Laravel app. I do not want users to be able to download the files if they are not logged into the system and not by directly going to the URL. Can someone please help me achieve this? I think I may need to somehow set the document as private but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that I know of:

- Returning a **temporary** signed URL which the user can use to download the file directly from S3.
- Streaming or downloading the file from S3 through your application.

For the first option you can use the `Storage` facade's [`temporaryUrl` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls) like this to allow access for 5 minutes:

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
    'file.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

To download the file through your server you could return:

```
return Storage::download('file.jpg');
```

Don't quote me on the following, but I think the advantage of using the S3 temporary url is that the download doesn't have to happen through your server which frees up your server for other requests. The benefit of downloading through your server is that you would be able to authenticate against every request and there won't be a temporary url which a user would be able to share.

Comment: You are correct on the benefit of the S3 temporary signed URL.  You offload the work AWS instead of your server.